# Internet Explorer Flash blocks

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, flex4, webserver, flash-builder

My problem is -

i am accessing flash content in IE.I am getting this error all the time.

**Error - Alternate HTML content should be placed here. This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. Get Flash .**

I installed Adobe Flash Player,but again it's showing same message.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you do not have the correct Flash player version installed.

Keep in mind that Flash Player for IE is **not** the same as Flash Player for other browsers.

Also, try to embed your swf with SWFObject as described here: 
[SWF object - why should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213930/swf-object-why-should-i-use-it/6218326#6218326)